# Adding multiple lines in ggplot2 with dates

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Struggled with this question for a while and not sure what's going on. I know this question will definitely demonstrate my deficiency with ggplot.

I have a script like this that functions nicely:

```
beta.bray= c(0.681963714,0.73301985,0.6797153,0.79358052,0.85055556,0.76297686,0.60653007)

beta.bray.gradient=c(0.182243513, 0.565267411,0.427449441,0.655012391,0.357146893,0.286457524,0.338706138)

Date=c("07/18/14","07/26/14","08/19/14","08/25/14", "07/25/15","08/22/15", "07/26/16")
dat=data.frame(Date, beta.bray, beta.bray.gradient)

test<-ggplot(dat, aes(x=reorder(Date, x=fct_inorder(Date)), y=beta.bray, group=1))+geom_line(linetype="dashed")+geom_point()+
  labs(x="Date", y="β, multiple-site dissimilarity", title="SNARL riffle site/site β through time, 2014-2016") +coord_cartesian(xlim=c(1,7),ylim=c(.58,.85))

test
```

But when I want to add another line for beta.bray.gradient, I can't get *anything* to work. I think it has something to do with the way I used aes() in the above code, but I didn't know how else to do it, in order to use reorder() and fct_inorder() to make sure the dates are plotted in the right way. Here's an example of a way I tried adding the second line:

```
    test<-ggplot(dat, aes(x=reorder(Date, x=fct_inorder(Date)), y=beta.bray, group=1))+geom_line(linetype="dashed")+geom_point()+
  geom_line(dat, aes(y=beta.bray.gradient, linetype="c"))+
  labs(x="Date", y="β, multiple-site dissimilarity", title="SNARL riffle site/site β through time, 2014-2016") +coord_cartesian(xlim=c(1,7),ylim=c(.58,.85))
```

In these situations we see a multitude of errors, in this case `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval`

Answer (score 1):

I would think it best to use actual date objects for the x axis and reshape your data into a long format:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

beta.bray <- c(0.681963714,0.73301985,0.6797153,0.79358052,0.85055556,0.76297686,0.60653007)
beta.bray.gradient <- c(0.182243513, 0.565267411,0.427449441,0.655012391,0.357146893,0.286457524,0.338706138)
Date <- as.Date(c("07/18/14","07/26/14","08/19/14","08/25/14", "07/25/15","08/22/15", "07/26/16"),"%m/%d/%y")

dat <- data.frame(Date, beta.bray, beta.bray.gradient) %>%
    gather(key = "grp",value = "val",beta.bray,beta.bray.gradient)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Date, y = val, group = grp,color = grp)) + 
    geom_line(linetype="dashed") + 
    geom_point() + 
    labs(x="Date", y="β, multiple-site dissimilarity", 
             title="SNARL riffle site/site β through time, 2014-2016") + 
    coord_cartesian(xlim=Date[c(1,7)])
```